# estimatedHeightForRowAt is not called on scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

Why method `estimatedHeightForRowAt` of the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol is not called when we are scrolling `UITableView`?

Method `estimatedHeightForRowAt` is called only when we initialize UITableView.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Method estimatedHeightForRowAt is called only when we initialize UITableView.

Correct. It is called for all rows up front, so we can estimate the whole height of the table content. That is exactly what it is for.

When you scroll and the new rows are about to appear, those are now real rows with real cells in them, so now you must give the *real* heights!

Comment: If my dataSource will contain 1000 items it will recalculate height for them and reuse it in the heightForRowAt if we wear using UITableViewAutomaticDimension ?

Comment: Are you trying to use self sizing cells of different heights?

Comment: Then you are doing this wrong. Just set the estimated row height for the table itself, set the table row height to automatic, do not implement any height delegate methods, and let the constraints size the cell from the inside out.

Comment: @matt I've found when using autolayout with a lot of constraints in a tableview with self sizing cells, a table wide estimated height does not perform well especially on older devices with a fast scroll rate when there is a large variability in cell heights (200px for example). The only way I got rid of noticeably degraded scrolling performance (lagging, jumping, etc) was to implement `estimatedHeightForRowAt` and return accurate estimates.

Comment: @mistahenry That’s correct. The fastest way is to do what we did before estimated heights existed: calculate all heights yourself in advance.