# what is the difference heightForRowAt vs estimatedHeightForRowAt?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Normally when  i want set my row height then set

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 300
    }
```

what is the benefited with `estimatedHeightForRowAt` when should i use it.

update! if i want to set estimatedHeightForRowAt:

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        return // what should i put here
    }
```

UPDATE:
Is there any effect tableview scrolling if i provide as my wish  estimatedHeightForRowAt? . for example i give in estimatedHeightForRowAt 500

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This difference becomes more meaningful when you have some **custom** cells which their height is different from most of your other cells. In that case the OS use `estimatedHeightForRowAt` as a default (This optimizes your loading time), but then if specified a different height for a row then it would use that.

As for what to put there:

If there is no variation then you put the same 300. Basically you put your default/most expected height there. For the heightForRowAt depending on your needs you may want to do [switch based on section/row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945923/switch-that-checks-nsindexpaths-row-and-section/35945961#35945961) and change height. If don't have any variations then still just put 300 there

---

I'm not sure if this is why you asked or not, but if you were asking this because you had dynamic tableViewCells with different heights, then the solution is:

1. Use Auto Layout when creating your table view cells.
2. Set the tableview `rowHeight` to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`.
3. Set the `estimatedRowHeight` or implement the height estimation delegate  method.

Basically do:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {  
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 80 // or any other number that makes sense for your cells
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

For more see this [RW Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells) and this high voted [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights)

---

## NOTE

If you don’t give the `estimatedRowHeight` then tableview will dequeue a lot more cells, because it’s trying to be smart and needs to prepare itself for smooth scrolling. It will trigger both your `cellForRow` & `willDisplay` callbacks

If you give `estimatedRowHeight` a value, then it won’t dequeue cells offscreen anymore

Comment: @cristainlika3 If there no variation then you put the same 300. Basically you put your default/most expected height there. For the `heightForRowAt` depending on your needs you may want to do switch based on section/row and change height. If don't have any variations then still just put 300 there

Comment: what do you mean by section/row and change height ?

Comment: how can i put section height what do you mean by section change height ?

Comment: @cristainlika3 you can change sectionHeight using a different method. Using this method you can change height of a row using switches. See the last code snippet of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35945961/5175709)

Comment: is there any effect tableview scrolling if `estimatedHeightForRowAt` is wrong . for example i give in `estimatedHeightForRowAt` 500

Comment: @cristainlika3 Yes. It's not substantial, but the more you make quick changes in your tableView and scroll data...the more it becomes important. To be honest I wouldn't spend too much time on this. Just do the right thing. Set your best educated guess in the estimate and then make whatever necessary changes in the `heightForRowAt`

Comment: is it possible to `estimatedHeightForRowAt` less than `heightForRowAt`?

Comment: @cristainlika3 I've answered that. Yes! + you can try yourself.

Answer (score 5):

As specified in the [iOS documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614926-tableview):

> If the table contains variable height rows, it might be expensive to calculate all their heights and so lead to a **longer load time**. Using estimation allows you to defer some of the cost of geometry calculation from load time to scrolling time.

Comment: can you share your own language

Comment: This might give you some context: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40341652/estimatedheightforrowat-is-not-called-on-scroll Basically, it's just a design decision to improve performance. Unless you have thousands of cells, I don't think it can make a difference. What are you trying to implement?

Comment: Is the height of your cells always the same? If this is the case, then you will have the same value as in `heightForRowAt`.

Comment: if not what should i do

Comment: Let's see if this is a good explanation. You need to provide a simple approximation. Imagine an app like Instagram. The `UITableView` gets populated with images of various heights. The thing is that we don't know the real height of each image until the download has been completed. But we still have to provide a height for the cells! So in the meantime we just provide an approximation (maybe, the average image height on Instagram). The cell will eventually get redrawn using the value provided by `heightForRowAt` (that's the real image height). If it's still unclear, let me know.

Comment: is there any effect tableview scrolling if `estimatedHeightForRowAt` is wrong . for example i give in estimatedHeightForRowAt  500 .