# Difference between estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath and heightForRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, heightforrowatindexpath

Hello can anyone help me to know difference between following two methods.

**First :**

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 100;
}
```

**Second :**

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 100;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: refer tis link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45267576/what-is-the-difference-heightforrowat-vs-estimatedheightforrowat

Comment: You can also check this link for deep understanding : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`heightForRowAtIndexPath` is the real height. Cell's height is 100.

`estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` isn't the real height. The Cell estimates the height as 100. The actual height is then calculated based on the constraint